# generating textboxes in a Windows Store app

Tags: c#, layout, grid, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to generate textboxes in a Windows store app using a button so that each new textbox generated (after recupering its value from a textBox) sits bellow the previous one

I've tried with

```
private void addBtn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs {
   int t = 100;
   TextBlock myTextBlock = new TextBlock();
   myGrid.Children.Add(myTextBox);
   myTextBlock.Text = taskTb.Text;
   myTextBlock.Width = 300;
   myTextBlock.Height = 300;
   myTextBlock.FontSize = 25;
   myTextBox.Margin = new Thickness(20,t,100,100);
   t = t + 100;
}
```

But it didn't work, what I am missing here?

Comment: What's not working about it?

Comment: textBoxes sit on top of eatch others

Comment: Have you considered putting them in a `<StackPanel>` or similar?

Comment: I've got this idea but I didn't know how to put textboxes inside a StackPanel using c#

Comment: Just swap `myGrid` for your StackPanel...

Comment: Stop.  Stop right now.  Throw away everything you have done so far.  Go learn how MVVM works.  Now start again, spending a fraction of the time you will by trying to add UI elements via code.

Comment: @RowlandShaw same result ,is there a way to insert the next textbox in the next row?

Comment: @Will ok I'll check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the error is that every time you are putting a new TextBox *at exactly the same position*.

The variable `t` is always 0 at the time you are adding a new `TextBox`, it would not increment as you expect, you should declare `t` as a field of the class, not as a temporary variable inside the method.

Or try `StackPanel`, let the `StackPanel` arranges (vertically stacks) the TextBoxes for you.